# Custom Colors on ThemeColor class

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have trying to set a custom color to a FileDecorationProvider class, the color should be set to text. I have been using charts colors but that limits me to like 6 colors.

The below method works but I am limited to chart colors(like 6 of them)

```java
async provideFileDecoration(uri: vscode.Uri): Promise<FileDecoration | undefined> {
    if (uri.fsPath === '\\temp11') {
         return {
             color: new ThemeColor("charts.red")
         };
    }
        
    return undefined;
}
```

But I would like to something like this:

```java
return {
    color: new ThemeColor("#0000ff")
};
```

Use HexCode to set a custom color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ThemeColor` API only supports *workbench colors* (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference), which means hex values are not allowed. And since `provideFileDecoration` only works with `ThemeColor` and not `string`, you won't be able to use hex values at all.

You could however, define a new color for your extension (via https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.colors), so the end user will be allowed to define its own color, via hex values.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

As @alefragnani suggests, you can define a new color in the `package.json` like this:

```
"contributes": {

    "colors": [
        {
            "id": "editorManager.treeItemTextForeground",   // your custom name here
            "description": "Color for a TreeIteem label",   // your description
            "defaults": {
                "dark": "#00ccff",   // your own defined colors, not just references to other exisiting themeColors
                "light": "#00ccff",
                "highContrast": "errorForeground"  // you can also use existing color theme references here
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and then use it wherever a themeColor is accepted:

```
color: new ThemeColor("editorManager.treeItemTextForeground")
```

The end user will also be able to modify that color in their settings `colorCustomizations`.

Comment: Hi @Mark, any idea on how I could add tabColoe progamtically without updating the settings.json file. Pretty much this question [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/312).

Comment: It isn't possible now.  You can decorate a TreeItem and the Explorer with a FileDecorater (simultaneously unfortunately), but not a tab label.  See for example https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47916 - there are a few issues asking for the ability to style tab labels but they all redirect to open issues.